# Fetch the unmatched data from different tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Lets say there are three table T1,T2 and T3. The values in T2 and T3 are linked with T1. I want to fetch records that are present in T1 but not in T2 marked as '1', records that are present in T1 but not in T3 as 2, and if record is present in T1 but not present in T2 and T3 , then marked as '3'.

Comment: Any code you tried so far?

Comment: Hi, please edit the question, post table definitions, example data

Answer (score 0):

Following example can help:

```
Select T1.ID, 
CASE WHEN T2.ID IS NULL THEN 1 END AS T1T2,
CASE WHEN T3.ID IS NULL THEN 2 END AS T1T3,
CASE WHEN T2.ID IS NULL AND T3.ID IS NULL THEN 3 END AS T1T2T3
From T1 LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.ID = T2.ID
LEFT JOIN T3
ON T1.ID = T3.ID;
```

Cheers!!